2-cells in the double category of 2-functors
Mike Shulman has in the answer to my previous question argued that for 2-categories $C$ and $K$ there is a double category whose objects are 2-functors between them and morphisms are lax and colax transformations.
In my mind I was interested in the cases where $K$ is cocomplete so the description as a double category of algebras for a concrete monad made sense to me at the time. Now thinking about it, I am lacking the understanding of the 2-cells in the general case of $[C,K]$ are, i.e. when the functor double category is not a double category of algebras for the monad in the answer. What are these 2-cells in double category of 2-functors?
Also a concrete reference defining either the functor double category or more generally an internal functor category in C (assuming C is well-behaved) for another internal functor category would be welcome.

If you write down what the 2-cells are in the cocomplete/monadic case, you can pass across adjunctions to get a description of those same 2-cells that also makes sense in the general case.

@MikeShulman which adjunctions do you mean here? A free cocompletion pseudoadjunction between Cat and Cocomp? if so that mostly answers my question. I need to work out the details though.

I should have said relative pseudoadjunction i think and the relativity makes me fail to immediately see how to pass across them.

No, I mean the hom-tensor adjunction, the same way you identify algebras of that monad with 2-functors.
